# Can I combine load() and append() in JQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day guys, can I combine `load()` and `append()` in JQuery/Ajax?

ex.

can I combine `load()` and `prepend()`? ex.

```
$('#notify').load(' #notify',function(){
     $('#notification').prepend(`
      <li>notif1</li>
      <li>notif2</li>
  `);
})
```

Updated:

The original code was like this.

```
function notif(){
    $.ajax({
        url: `/iaccs-hook-notifications`,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);
            // if (data.success){
            //     $("#notify").load(" #notify");
            // }   

            if (data.length > 0) {


                //proceed

                $('#btn-notif').addClass('js-has-new-notification'); 



                $('#notif-list').append(`

                    <li>
                        <div class="an-info-single unread">
                            <a href="{{url('iaccs-hook-list')}}">
                                <span class="icon-container important">
                                    <i class="icon-setting"></i>
                                </span>
                            <div class="info-content">
                                <h5 class="user-name">Update Client</h5>
                                <p class="content"><i class="icon-clock"></i>${data[0].created_at}</p>
                            </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                `);
            } 



        },
        error: function(err){
            swal('Error!','Please report this issue.', 'error');
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // let refreshNotification = () => {
    //     $('#notify').load(location.href + ' #notify');
    //     $(this).unwrap()
    // }



    notif();

    var socket = io('http://www.iaccs-admin-console.test' + ':8080');
    socket.on("message", function(message){

        notif()


        // $('.unread').on('click',function(){
        //     $.get('/markAsRead');
        // });

    });

});
```

and here is the view.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="notify">

    <p class="an-info-count">Notifications <span>{{count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications)}}</span></p>
    <div class="an-info-content notifications-info notifications-content">


            <ul class="nav" id="notif-list">

            </ul>

    </div> <!-- end .AN-INFO-CONTENT -->
    <div class="an-info-show-all-btn">
            <a class="an-btn an-btn-transparent fluid rounded uppercase small-font" href="#">Show all</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with the code above is that you need to refresh the page first for the whole drop down menu will notify the user and display the count of the notifications.

Comment: is your above jquery fuction working proper or not ?

Comment: Did you give it a try? What were your results?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry, mjlowky the code maybe psued-code; just to get a better idea of what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: `jquery .load()` isn't chainable but you can use `.append()` in its callback. `.append()` is chainable so you can try to use chain `$('div').append(document.body).load('mysource.html #main')`. Please report results.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I tried it and didn't work it's just a imaginary code :)

Comment: @mjlowky It doesn't work sir.. it's just a imaginary code of what I want to achieve like musafar006 said.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I will try to study that sir... I edited my question...